# How to change common styles for redmine email messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email, redmine, redmine-plugins

I need to make some styles available for every html email message in my custom redmine plugin. So I should do something with mailer layout https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb

As this file doesn't contain any hook ( http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial#Using-hooks ) only thing I can imagine to do it in this case is to override the layout in the plugin.

Is there any way to avoid overriding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gem [`deface`](https://github.com/spree/deface) which can help you.

I changed some parts of the view on the fly using `deface`. Please see this [commit](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_better_journal/commit/c726266068e3a7ff56ff6947dd244070cbaf6741).